# End of line in CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read a CSV file for processing in Python. All I want is to associate the values of cities to a state in a dictionary which is present in the CSV all comma separated. After getting the name of state I want to get the cities as its values for which I want to know the end of line of the file.

My structure of CSV is like :

```
State,city1,city2,city3,city4,city5,..,cityn
```

Since all the states may not have values for all the cities, some city values are empty.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Is it possible that you'd be a bit clearer about what you actually intend to do?

Comment: Also, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I am storing the state as key and city names as values in a dictionary. So I want to know when is my line going to end so that I can process next line.

Comment: Initially I tried to separate, State and city with % and city names separated with comma. After spliting the line at % of 0 and 1 I know where is the state and city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you iterate over the file, it will automatically yield each line; in other words you don't need to know where the line ends:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
    for line in f: # this will automatically step over each line correctly
        bits = line.split(',')
        d[bits[0]] += bits[1:]

for state,cities in d.items():
    print('{} has {} cities: '.format(state, len(cities))
    for city in cities:
        print('\t{}'.format(city))
```

Comment: Ha, beat me to it!  I was just about to post the same (more or less) dictionary creation scheme as you when I saw you post pop up.  This is simple, effective, way of creating a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, two solutions to break your content on each new line:

```
with open(your_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        do_stuff()
```

or

```
for line in you_csv_content.split("\n"):
    do_stuff()
```